# How to save a Picture to a Picturebox?

Tags: c#

Here's the current code I have:

```
private void BrowsePicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Browse Picture
    {
        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        if(OFD.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Bitmap Image = new Bitmap(OFD.FileName);
            ProfilePicture.Image = Image;
            ProfilePicture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        }
    }
```

I would like to save the image on the `PictureBox` so that when the software is closed and opened again later, the image will still be in there. Can this can be done through `Properties.Settings`?

Comment: Here's my Idea what if when I Click Browse button Select my Image , it will display it on the PictureBox then save it to the software Directory. Then when the forms loads up it import that picture automatically from the directory. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you saving this data? You should save your setting in a place that you can read when you do the login action and then set the value in your `PictureBox`.

EDIT:

To save the image in your specific folder:

`Bitmap b = new Bitmap("your image location");
b.Save("your folder location + your image name with extension");`

To read the image and set into your `PictureBox` do this in the `Load` event:

`pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("your image location");`

Comment: Actually here's how it work, When someone Click on the Browse Button and select their image it displays on the PictureBox. I Would like the selected image to stay their when I close and reopen the form.

Comment: Well, you'll need to save this info somewhere, like a xml, json, etc. 
And then when you re-open the application make it read your file and set your `PictureBox` with your previously saved path.

Comment: This sound really difficult, Isn't their a simple way to simply save the file into a directory and when the form load the PictureBox load the following file?

Comment: ++ That seem great info, just something , I am a newbie to C# how to setup the directory "your image location" to the software directory itself. + When you saving the picture it save itself with a Name < 
'Bitmap b = new Bitmap("" "ImageName.bit")'

Comment: Use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` to get your application directory. It'll be something like this `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + '\\imageName.jpg'`

Comment: Worked* Thank you very much for helping me :)

Comment: @NatanielRichardt suggesting the application folder is not a good idea.  On some Windows environment that folder is read-only. Using the [MyDocuments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.specialdirectories.mydocuments(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [Current User Application Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.specialdirectories.currentuserapplicationdata(v=vs.110).aspx) would be best.  Because it allows multiple users on the same machine to have different data.

Comment: Ok I will take some time to learn about it , new plan Create a folder for the software in My Document to save Images and Info*

Comment: @BlackFrog I know. But he asked about how to do it, also if you take a look in his application its just some simple winform that will never be a problem to do this way.

Comment: Yes cuz this going to be only 1 Simple picture to load < only